# Why child class constructor when initializing parent's part used overrided version of method?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, overriding

Why `B()` when initializing part of class A using overrides method `print()` defined in class B?

Expected output:
A
4

Real output:
0
4

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new B();
    }
}

class A
{
    public A()
    {
        print();
    }
    
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    int a = 4;
    public B()
    {
        print();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overriden `print` in class `B`.

So if you call `print` on an instance of `B` it will always go there.

This also happens while a constructor is still running, which you seem to not have expected, and it can also cause problem because not all fields in `B` may have been initialized yet. For this reason, it is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors) to call any method from a constructor that is not `final`.

Your example nicely demonstrates that:

You say you expected to output of "A" for that first print statement, most people would have expected the output of "4", but what really happens is you get a "0" because the field `B.a` is not yet initialized.

---

```
public A()
    {
        print();
    }
```

Here, `print()` is not a static method, so this is short for `this.print()`. And even though you are in the constructor of class `A`, this was being called as part of `new B()` from the constructor of `B`, so `this` is an instance of `B` (at a point of time when the constructor of `B` has not yet fully done its work).